# Grep Link and Link name to create CSV file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to create a list of urls and names from a file. The links are displayed like this:

```
<table class="list">
  <tr><th valign="top">I</th><td><a href="main.asp">link45.php</a>, <a href="link.html">link</a>, <a href="link8.asp">link8</a>, <a href="link2.html">link 2</a></td></tr>

<tr><th valign="top">I</th><td><a href="main.asp">link45.php</a>, <a href="link.html">link</a>, <a href="link8.asp">link8</a>, <a href="link2.html">link 2</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

(there are probably some tr's and table tags in there also. please ignore the spaces at the start of the tags.

I need the output to be in a csv like format, but I am unsure how to do this with grep:

"linktoblah.html", "name of link"

I have a working grep which pulls out all of the links.html but not sure how I would pull out the name next to it.

```
cat list.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The line you showed can be extracted with

```
sed -e 's/.*=\(".*"\)>\(.*\)<.*$/\1, "\2"/'
```

Example:

```
echo '< a href="linktoblah.html">name of link < /a>.' | sed -a 's/.*=\(".*"\)>\(.*\)<.*$/\1, "\2"/'
```

produces

```
"linktoblah.html", "name of link "
```

Depending on what else is in your file, you may be able to replace the `grep` command with a selector in `sed`, like this:

```
sed -n -e '/href=/ s/.*=\(".*"\)>\(.*\)<.*$/\1, "\2"/p'
```

where the

```
/href=/
```

can be any regular expression that matches only the lines you want. The `p` at the end of the string means "and print", and the `-n` flag means "don't do anything unless there is a match". The combination of the two makes the separate `grep` unnecessary.

Comment: The spaces are not actually there, I just put them in so stackoverflow wouldn't hide the links. All the links are in a table so it would actually be displayed < td>link and link name < /td>. the sed is giving me invalid option -a ?

Comment: Not sure what happened there. Use `-e` flag (see edited post). I thought I had done a copy/paste from my command line...

Comment: Its pulling out more tags and only getting the first result (there are thousands)      <table class="sourcelist">
"page.aspx?=blah", "blah</a></td>"
    </table>

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way on a different post using PERL HTML::TableExtract.

[Get contents between table tags in everyfile in directory output to one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660677/get-contents-between-table-tags-in-everyfile-in-directory-output-to-one-file)

Many thanks to choroba for his input.

Comment: Using functions like that is much better than trying to do it yourself with regex.

Answer (score 0):

A new `awk`
Not sure if this what you are looking for, but here is what I get from the new data:

```
awk -F"[\"<>]" -v RS="href=\"" 'NR>1 {print  "\""$1"\",\""$3"\""}' file
"main.asp","link45.php"
"link.html","link"
"link8.asp","link8"
"link2.html","link 2"
"main.asp","link45.php"
"link.html","link"
"link8.asp","link8"
"link2.html","link 2"
```

Comment: @John J  Deleted my old answer, do to different data. It may be more what you are looking for.