# Get contents between table tags in everyfile in directory output to one file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have directory with about 900 html documents in it, each document contains the same table tags (easily defined) in that table is data which I need to extract and output in a csv format. What is the best way to do this and how can I do it?

Here is an example of what is in each html file which I need to extract

```
<table class="datalogs" cellspacing="5px">
                        <tr>< th>Data1</th><th>Data 2</th><th>Data 3</th><th>Data 4</th><th>Data 4< /th>< th>Data 5</th><th>Data 6</th></tr>
<tr class="odd"><td valign="top"><h4>123<br/></h4></td><td valign="top">AAA</td><td valign="top"><b>url here</b></td><td valign="top">Yes</td><td valign="top">None</td><td valign="top"></td><td valign="top"></td></tr><tr class="even">...
                        </table>
```

The ideal outcome would be
"123", "AAA", "url here", "Yes", "None", "", ""

If this cant be achieved in one go, then just extracting data between the table tags (defined by class="datalogs") and put all results into one file (this would be from a loop which goes through the directory and every file getting this table.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doable in Perl, with the help of [HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) and [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $te = 'HTML::TableExtract'
         ->new(headers => ['Data1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4',
                           'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6']);

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary       => 1,
                             eol          => "\n",
                             always_quote => 1,
                           });

while (@ARGV) {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
    my $html = do { local $/; <$IN> };
    $te->parse($html);
}
for my $table ($te->tables) {
    $csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, $_) for $table->rows;
}
```

I had to fix some error in your sample input (there should be no space between `<` and the tag name or `/`).

### Update

Adding the file names to the first column: a new TableExtract object created for each file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary       => 1,
                             eol          => "\n",
                             always_quote => 1,
                           });

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
    my $html = do { local $/; <$IN> };
    my $te = 'HTML::TableExtract'
             ->new(headers => ['Data1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4',
                               'Data 4', 'Data 5', 'Data 6']);
    $te->parse($html);
    $csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, [$file, @$_]) for ($te->tables)[0]->rows;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was because I didn't realise full tags were accepted in code tags. I am going to set this up and try now. I will let you know shortly. Thanks

Comment: That worked like a charm, got to love a bit of PERL. Many thanks for your help :D

Comment: How would you add an extra column to the CSV file, I would like to put part of the filename as the first column create so the rows can be identified.

Comment: @JohnJ: Unfortunately, this is not a small change, as the current approach accumulates the tables and prints them all at once when the file names are no longer known. Bigger changes to the algorithm are needed.

Comment: Damn thats what I thought, ok no worries I can do it a different way. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I appreciate your help, your a legend!